# Combining two fields from two different tables in SQL

Tags: sql, database

I have two tables:

**test:**

```
id
name
last_name
price
```

**test1**

```
id
name
price
```

I want to combine the two fields (price) from two tables and calculate their average. But I get an average of the field for each of these tables.

```
SELECT AVG(price) FROM test as p
UNION
SELECT AVG(price) FROM test1 as p
```

Comment: Columns, not fields... Do UNION ALL instead.

Comment: combine the two fields (price) from two tables and calculate their average for each pair of id and name?

Comment: Although most probably not relevant for such a basic question, but you should always add the tag for the DBMS you are using. Postgres, Oracle, DB2, ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT AVG(price) AS P FROM
(
    SELECT price FROM test
    UNION ALL
    SELECT price FROM test1
) AS TMP
```

I think you need `UNION ALL` to really include ALL prices, otherwise duplicate prices will be omitted, which may have influence on the average.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using subquery, or with clause:

```
WITH all_data as(
    SELECT id,name,price FROM test as t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id,name,price FROM test as t2
)
SELECT AVG(price) FROM all_data
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do average on the basis of name then:

1. you have to use union all and then group by name
2. find avg

if you just want avg then do Union all first then take avg